# How to render all json data in dynamic email template with handlebars in SendGrid code editor?

Tags: json, handlebars.js, sendgrid, email-templates

I have a question about the handlebar format functions that are available in the transaction template code editor in SendGrid (https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars).

In my case I want to render a part of the json test data or the whole json test data as text in the email (f.e. for test purposes).

I can loop over the root properties and values of the json test data without knowing any property names like this:

```
<table>
      {{#each this}}
           <tr>
                <td>{{@key}}</td>
                <td>{{this}}</td>
           </tr>
      {{/each}}
 </table>
```

But this will render [object Object] as value for deeper objects or arrays.

Is there a way to render the array/deeper objects als json text? Or are there any methods available like 'isArray' or 'isObject' to detect that there is more? Or a 'log' method to log the json as text?

Tried with operators like #each, this, @key etc.

Comment: I think that the simplest thing to do, if it is possible, would be to `JSON.stringify()` your data object and pass that single, string value to your template for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: @76484 unfortunately you cannot run JavaScript code inside of Handlebars templates. You can register your own helpers which is how you add JavaScript functionality into the Handlebar template, but that's not available when using SendGrid.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot extend handlebars in SendGrid as you would be able to do when running handlebars yourself. If you could, it'd be easy to add a `JSON.stringify` helper function, or create a recursive template.

What you're doing is the only way AFAIK. I'd suggest using `<ul>` + `<li>` as it will be easier to parse visually with the indentation.
Here's an example of doing this 4 levels deep which includes the index in case there's an array instead of an object:

```
<ul>
{{#each this}}
<li>
    {{@key}}: {{this}}
    <ul>
    {{#each this}}
    <li>
        {{@key}}: {{this}}
        <ul>
        {{#each this}}
        <li>
            {{@key}}: {{this}}    
            <ul>
            {{#each this}}
            <li>
                {{@key}}: {{this}}
            </li>
            {{/each}}
             </ul>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
         </ul>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
     </ul>
</li>
{{/each}}
 </ul>
```

When using this test data:

```json
{
    "greeting": "Ahoy!",
    "wish":{
        "text": "Happy holidays!",
        "from": {
            "email": "niels@localhost",
            "name": "Niels"
        }
    },
    "planets": [
        "Saturn",
        "Pluto",
        "Jupiter"
    ]
}
```

The output will look like this:
[image: Email Output]